# How to get the the clicked values dynamically using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I Have the following code and I am trying to the output click text values dynamically and the date value as well. I am not sure what i am doign wrong its not returning anything when clicked

HTML

```
!--- start dynamic bit  data violation type is will be dynmically generated by the server---->

<h3  id="toggle-next" data-violation-type="1111" class="violation"> lorm 1 violation 1</h3>
<div  id="moreinfo-231">

<p> lorem ipsum </p>
<p> lorem ipsum </p>
<p> lorem ipsum </p>

</div>
<!--- start dynamic bit---->
<!-- end dynamic bit-->
<h3  id="toggle-next" data-violation-type="11232" class="violation"> lorm 2 violation 2</h3>
<div id="moreinfo-232">

<p> lorem ipsum 2</p>
<p> lorem ipsum 2</p>
<p> lorem ipsum 2</p>

</div>
<!-- end dynamic bit-->
```

JQUERY

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#toggle-next").find("h3").click(function(){
            alert($(this).text());  

    console.log(" you have clicked " +$(this).text());  
 console.log(" you have clicked data " +$(this).data("violation-type"));            
                            });




});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont need the `.find()` because it's the same element.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#toggle-next").click(function() {
    var clicked = $(this);
    alert(clicked.text());  
    console.log(" you have clicked " + clicked.text());  
    console.log(" you have clicked data " + clicked.data("violation-type"));            
  });
});
```

It's also a good idea to cache an object if you use it more than once, in this case you use `$(this)` 3 times so it must look it up in the DOM each time.

Also, you should change the `#toggle-next` to `.toggle-next` and make it `class="toggle-next"` instead of `id="toggle-next"`. You're only allowed to have 1 ID per page, and jQuery will stop looking after it finds one.

Answer (score 0):

Id of an element must be unique, so you need to use the class to select all those target `h3` elements. In your case all the `h3` elements have the class `violation` so use that.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("h3.violation").click(function() {
    alert($(this).text());
    console.log(" you have clicked " + $(this).text());
    console.log(" you have clicked data " + $(this).data("violation-type"));
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
!--- start dynamic bit data violation type is will be dynmically generated by the server---->

<h3 id="toggle-next" data-violation-type="1111" class="violation"> lorm 1 violation 1</h3>

<div id="moreinfo-231">
  <p>lorem ipsum</p>
  <p>lorem ipsum</p>
  <p>lorem ipsum</p>
</div>
<!--- start dynamic bit---->
<!-- end dynamic bit-->

<h3 id="toggle-next" data-violation-type="11232" class="violation"> lorm 2 violation 2</h3>

<div id="moreinfo-232">
  <p>lorem ipsum 2</p>
  <p>lorem ipsum 2</p>
  <p>lorem ipsum 2</p>
</div>
<!-- end dynamic bit-->
```

Your selector has another problem, that is `#toggle-next` is the `h3` element so `$("#toggle-next").find("h3")` won't return any elemnet